# mysql insert date past thursday

Tags: php, mysql, date

So I'm making a program that inserts some information in the database with a specific date. First, I made the program so that the data would be inserted on the current date, that was easy.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (Date) VALUES (now())";
```

but now, I want the program to insert the date of the past thursday in the database. i.e. today is 28/01/2015, When I would run the program today, 22/01/2015 should appear in the database, because that's the date of the past thursday. but when I run the program tomorrow, a new row in the database should be added and this date should be 28/1/2015, because tomorrow is thursday and 28/01 would be the last thursday then.
I'm using the msql syntax, not msqli.

Btw: I'm a complete noob in programming and didn't found this on the internet, so don't kill me if this is a stupid question please :)

Comment: I just had this problem myself a few days ago and found this solution to be excellent: http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-select-this-wednesday-or-other.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need last Thursday if today isn't Thursday ,you can get that date this way:

```
$s = (date('D') === 'Thu') ? "now" : "last Thursday";// Thursday check
$lastThursday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($s));
```

and then insert it this way:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (Date) VALUES ('$lastThursday')";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tested this code but it looks like it isn't working. It gives date 0000-00-00 in the database...

Comment: sorry, my mistake, you have to put `$lastThursday` within quotes in the `$sql` query. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (Date) VALUES (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) - 3 + 7) DAY))
```

Generally what it does is ... it checks what is the difference between `now()` and desired day, and returns a day in 7 days minus this difference.

Answer (score 0):

Or do it the OOP way:

```
$thursday = new DateTime();
if ($now->format('D') !== 'Thu') {
    $thursday->modify('last thursday');
}
echo $thursday->format('Y-m-d');
```